# Determinant of sum of matricies.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose that I have an $m \times n$ matrix $X$.  Let $X_a$ be a matrix created using some of the columns of $X$. (So for example, say you take the 1st, 4th, and 9th column of $X$). Let $X_{b}$ be the matrix of all the remaining columns of $X$ that are not in $X_a$.

Can I say that $\det({XX^T}) = \det({X_aX_a^T + X_bX_b^T}$)?

Tentatively, it seems like the minors/cofactors of $X_aX_a^T$ and $X_bX_b^T$ be also be (exactly) the minors/cofactors of $XX^T$. Using Laplace's determinant decomposition formula, can we somehow prove this statement? (or another way)?

Comment: $X_a^T X_a$ and $X_b^T X_b$ may haven’t the same size. Do you mean $XX^T = X_aX_a^T + X_bX_b^T$, which is indeed true?

Comment: @user251257 Yes. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: no need for the determinant. The matrices themselves are equal.